# Structured Streaming Rollback files in case of Exception

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

In my Structured Streaming application, I am reading the data from MQ and doing some transformation and writing the results to `kafka`. I have implemented the MQ custom source.

My question is how to roll back the messages to MQ incase of exceptions during the transformation or while writing the messages to Kafka.

I am reading the messages as bulk, say 5000 messages per batch, but while writing the results, if `kafka` goes down, what are the ways we can rollback the messages?

Is there any approach we can rollback or recover messages when using custom source (any not distributed source like MQ).